# Comma separated column value from Temporary Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am inserting select statement result to Temporary table. I want its one column value comma separated, so I tried following but it is not working.

```
SELECT @IdList = COALESCE(@IdList+',' ,'') + s.Id 
        FROM (SELECT Id FROM #_TempStudentTable) as s
```

I have checked data in `#_TempStudentTable`, it is having data. But when i try to display `IdList`, it returns NULL.
Help me. I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Initialize `@IdList` to `''`.  `NULL` values just beget more `NULL` values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I tried ur solutiomn but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @IdList VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @IdList  = COALESCE(@IdList  + ',','') + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(100)) 
FROM #_TempStudentTable

SELECT @IdList
```

**You can get it without variable also using XML like below**

```
SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM    #_TempStudentTable
            FOR XML PATH (''))
            , 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: I dont't know what problem with the first one. It works fine with numeric field but failed for varchar field.

Comment: Second one is working. I don't know what's the problem with first one.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you may use the below query to get a list of comma separated column names/headers:

```
SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + CAST(name AS VARCHAR(50))
            FROM (
                SELECT name
                FROM tempdb.sys.columns
                WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#temptablename')
                ) k
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
```